# Java and CANopen

Tags: java, automation, network-protocols, can-bus, canopen

### Background

I am required to create a Java program on a laptop to receive/send CANopen messages.

RJ45 is chosen to be the network's physical medium. I am new to CANopen and Java communications programming.

Pardon me if I appear to be uninitiated. The truth is, I have been reading up a lot, but I still do not know how to get started.

### Questions

1. Other than connecting a PC to the CANbus network, what else does the CAN-PC adapter do?
2. Is it possible to connect the laptop to the CANbus network without the CAN-PC adapter?
3. If a CAN-PC adapter is required, what sort of adapter should I use? PCMCIA, parallel, serial, usb, etc.?
4. How do I get started in writing the java program to listen/write CANopen messages?
5. What libraries should I use?
6. Do I need to create my own drivers?
7. Should my program handle heart-beat monitoring, error detection, etc.? Or are these taken care of by the CAN-PC adapter?
8. How do I retrieve specific information from a CANbus node?
9. How is the EDS file and object dictionary created? Does every node require them?

   10. How do I simulate a CAN network to test my Java program without buying CAN hardware?

Answer (score 12):

That's a lot of questions. I have never done any CAN related programming in Java, but let's see which questions I might answer anyway:

> 1) Other than connecting a PC to the
>   CANbus network, what else does the
>   CAN-PC adapter do?

It depends mainly on which CAN controller that is embedded in your adapter. But basically it just handles the low-level stuff like bus-arbitration, error-handling, retransmissions and message buffering.

> 2) Is it possible to connect the
>   laptop to the CANbus network without
>   the CAN-PC adapter?

No.

> 3) If a CAN-PC adapter is required,
>   what sort of adapter should I use?
>   PCMCIA, parallel, serial, usb, etc?

On a laptop? I would choose a USB interface. I have good experience with Kvaser's interfaces.

> 4) How do I get started in writing the
>   java program to listen/write CANopen
>   messages?

Depends on the API for your adapter. The API will most probably be C-based, so I would at least start out with some simple C test programs. The CAN-interface supplier probably have some good examples.

> 5) What libraries should I use?

Probably the one supplied with your CAN-interface, at least for the basic CAN part. For the CANopen part, there are some commercial CANopen stacks available and perhaps even some free. I doubt there are any written in Java.
You could also implement the necessary parts of the CANopen stack yourself if you are only doing simple communication.

> 6) Do I need to create my own drivers?

Generally no. Depends on your operating system and CAN-interface model. Select a CAN interface with drivers for your operating system.

> 7) Should my program handle heart-beat
>   monitoring / error detection / etc? Or
>   are these taken care of by the CAN-PC
>   adapter?

The CANopen stack should handle that on the CANopen level. The low level CAN bus error handling is taken care of by your interface.

> 8) How do I retrieve specific
>   information from a CANbus node?

I don't know what you mean here. PDOs or SDOs depending on what kind of information you want.

> 9) How is the EDS file and object
>   dictionary created? Does every node
>   require them?

You don't genereally need to create an EDS file, but might be useful for documentation purposes. The object-dictionary is implemented in software. Some parts of the OD are mandatory if making something standards-compliant.

> 10) How do I simulate a CAN network to
>   test my java program without buying
>   CAN hardware?

I wouldn't... A meaningful bus simulator would probably be more expensive to develop than to just bu a CAN adapter. Note that many CAN adapters contain dual interfaces, so you may do communication tests on a real CAN bus with little more hardware than just the adapter and a couple of termination resistors.

Comment: The EDS file is mandatory for a CANopen compliant product. It's needed both by configuration, service and system design tools.